# Apache Flink: guideliness for setting parallelism?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to get some simple rules or guidelines for what values to set for 
operator or job 
parallelism. It would seem to me that it should be a number <= the number of 
available task 
slots?

For example, suppose I have 2 task manager machines, each with 4 task slots. 
Assuming no other jobs running on the cluster, would I set the parallelism 
for operations 
like filter and map to 8? If not, what would be a reasonable number?

What happens if you request more parallelism than they are task slots? In 
example above, 
what happens if I set parallelism to 12 on the operations? I'm assuming it 
would just use as many 
as are available?

Also, it would seem that you would not want to hardcode the parallelism into 
your source code, since 
you would want to have a rough idea of available task slots when  you submit 
the job? 
Should you set parallelism to all operators roughly the same or different 
values, and what would guide 
that decision?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In general it is a good idea to not hardcode the parallelism because it is usually the responsibility of operations to decide how many resources to assign to your job. Moreover, the resource requirements usually depend on your SLAs and the actual workload and are, thus, program independent and should be treated separately.

With [Flink 1.5.0](https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html#latest-stable-release-v150) when running on Yarn or Mesos, you only need to decide on the parallelism of your job and the system will make sure that it starts enough TaskManagers with enough slots to execute your job. This happens completely dynamically and you can even change the parallelism of your job at runtime.

If you are using the standalone mode or if your Yarn/Mesos cluster has not enough resources/slots available, then the job will fail with a `NoResourceAvailableException` if the system cannot obtain the required slots.

Comment: sounds like a good advice. but what about the numeric examples that were presented ? are they correct ?

Comment: Which numeric examples are you referring to?

Comment: He was asking 
>> "For example, suppose I have 2 task manager machines, each with 4 task slots. Assuming no other jobs running on the cluster, would I set the parallelism for operations like filter and map to 8? ... what happens if I set it to 12" etc

Comment: Ideally you set the parallelism to the number of slots you have in your cluster. In batch jobs you can also set the number of parallelism to something higher but you won't gain much by doing this.

Comment: Hey @Till Rohrmann, so Yarn will scale out if necessary dynamically?

Comment: Yes, Flink will request TMs dynamically when deploying on Yarn or Mesos.

Comment: @TillRohrmann, would it also scale down if load goes down? I am basically exploring dynamic scaling for a flink application. As the load goes up/down, I need nodes to be added/removed.

Comment: At the moment, this is not yet supported by Flink out of the box. You would need an external tool which monitors the load and makes scaling decision based on it.