# Configuring core usage per slot in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a cluster of `3` machines with `4` cores each. Each machine has one task manager. I know that the number of slots in Flink can be controlled by `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots`. I initially had allotted `12` slots in total (every task manager had `4` slots). Although, there is no explicit CPU isolation among slots (as mentioned [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/concepts/flink-architecture/#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20no%20CPU%20isolation%20happens%20here%3B%20currently%20slots%20only%20separate%20the%20managed%20memory%20of%20tasks.)), I assume that each slot is roughly using 1 core. Am I right in assuming this?

I haven't mentioned any slot sharing group in my code and my pipeline does not have any blocking edges. The parallelism of each task is the same and is equal to the number of slots. I am assuming that one subtask from each task will be in a slot. Am I correct in this understanding?

After some conversation ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72345290/intuition-for-setting-appropriate-parallelism-of-operators-in-flink) for the curious minds :-)), I wanted to increase the cores per slot to `2` for my experiments. So, I reduced the `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots` to `2` on each machine? After doing this, I see that the Flink WebUI shows `6` slots is total and `2` slots for each task manager. I have also reduced the parallelism of each task to `6`. Is this all that I need to do?

Note: I am not using the MVP feature of fine grained resource management right now.

Comment: I hope what you find matches my expectations, but it could be that I've overlooked some factor that will produce different results in your case. If you find something surprising, I'd like to hear about it.

Comment: Sure. I will update you if I find something odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds right.

Each Task Manager is a single JVM. A *task slot* doesn't correspond to anything physical -- it's just an abstract resource managed by the Flink scheduler. Each *task* in a task slot is an instance of an *operator chain* in the execution graph, and each task is single-threaded. No two instances of the same operator chain will ever be scheduled into the same slot.

All of the threads for all of the tasks in all of the slots in given task manager will compete for the resources available to that JVM: cores, memory, etc.

As you have noted, there is no way to explicitly set the number of cores per slot. And there's no requirement that the number be an integer. You could, for example, decide that your 4-core TMs are each providing 3 slots, for a total parallelism of 9 across the 3 TMs.